# Find location registered in database by the given longitude and latitude - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, geolocation, e-commerce, latitude-longitude

I'm working on an e-commerce, and I encountered an problem understanding the way to find a location by the given (**longitude - latitude**) and get the matched location from **locations** table in the database.

I have **locations** table to store all my country's cities there.

Ex:

| city_name | fee | lng | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Babil. | 12 | 47.0983 | 31.90043 |
| Baghdad. | 5 | 47.0983 | 31.90043 |
| ............ | ... | ....... | ...... |

> the above **lng** & **lat** are fake.

What I want is:

when a user select his location on the maps from the mobile app, the app sends his selected location's (**longitude - latitude**) through the API endpoint:

e.g. /locations?lng=xxx&lat=xxx

then the server (Laravel App) should check the (lng-lat) with the **locations** table to find user's city according to the given creds.

sorry if I couldn't explain well but this is how it should be, not check for the nearest location or something like that.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Aless55I tried the best answer here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-store-locations-with-laravel-and-eloquent and it worked fine, but! the the max_distance is the problem with this because when I try it on a small city it returned successfully, and when trying on a big city returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation what i can understand is that you want to find cities nearest to user position. You can use distance farmula here that is

=ACOS( SIN(lat1 * PI()/180) * SIN(lat2 * PI()/180) + COS(lat1 * PI()/180) * COS(lat2 * PI()/180) * COS(lon2 * PI()/180-lon1 * PI()/180) ) * 6371000

You can use this formula to convert lat, lng into distance and then can sort your data according to distance.

Or if you want to just query data according to given lat, lng then you can simply run select query on your table. One thing to make sure is that you must store lat,lng with 8 decimal places to find accurate result.

Comment: here what do you mean by (lat1, lat2) and (lon1, lon2) ?

Comment: So it is used to calculate distance between two sets of (lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2). 

(lat1, lon1) could be already saved data in your database.
(lat2, lon2) could be your user input.